# Common techniques / tips for messy pdf parsing?

Tags: python, parsing, pdf

I'm working on converting 100s of pdf files (500+ pages each) into csv data files. The pdfs have valuable University class grade data that cannot be found elsewhere (These are public record).

I am attempting to use Python and PyPDF to parse through it and extract data. I will attach my current progress below:

[PDF example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuDyo.png)

The format is for the most part predictable. I cannot blindly parse, I will have to define some **parsing rules** to extract my data.

*For example: I know when I see the string "**Listing**" it is followed by the **class code**.*

Are there any advice or techniques to doing this? Is this approaching the bounds of natural language processing?

```
['Miami', 'PlanHonorsCross', 'ListingACE', '113', 'B', 'Yang', 'Eun', 'Chong', 'Reading', 'Writing', 'Acad', 'ContextsNN', 'A+AA-B+BB-C+CC-D+DD-FWWPWFIXYPSAvg', 'GPA', '1523010101000000000003.38%7.135.714.321.40.07.10.07.10.07.10.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.0ACE', '113', 'C', 'Duffield', 'Ebru', 'D.', 'Reading', 'Writing', 'Acad', 'ContextsNN', 'A+AA-B+BB-C+CC-D+DD-FWWPWFIXYPSAvg', 'GPA', '6030120000000100000003.63%46.20.023.10.07.715.40.00.00.00.00.00.00.07.70.00.00.00.00.00.00.0ACE', '113', 'D', 'Duffield', 'Ebru', 'D.', 'Reading', 'Writing', 'Acad', 'ContextsNN', 'A+AA-B+BB-C+CC-D+DD-FWWPWFIXYPSAvg', 'GPA', '5211310000000000000003.59%38.515.47.77.723.17.70.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.0ACE', '113', 'F', 'Duffield', 'Ebru', 'D.', 'Reading', 'Writing', 'Acad', 'ContextsNN', 'A+AA-B+BB-C+CC-D+DD-FWWPWFIXYPSAvg', 'GPA', '6132000000000100000003.81%46.27.723.115.40.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.07.70.00.00.00.00.00.00.0Course', 'Total', 'ACE', '113A+AA-B+BB-C+CC-D+DD-FWWPWFIXYPSAvg', 'GPA188910960202000200000003.44%27.312.113.615.213.69.10.03.00.03.00.00.00.03.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.0ACE', '310E', 'A', 'Marcus', 'Felice', 'J.', 'American', 'FilmNN', 'A+AA-B+BB-C+CC-D+DD-FWWPWFIXYPSAvg', 'GPA', '1312441012100100000002.84%4.814.34.89.519.019.04.80.04.89.54.80.00.04.80.00.00.00.00.00.00.0Course', 'Total', 'ACE', '310EA+AA-B+BB-C+CC-D+DD-FWWPWFIXYPSAvg', 'GPA1312441012100100000002.84%4.814.34.89.519.019.04.80.04.89.54.80.00.04.80.00.00.00.00.00.00.0Run:02/12/16', '@', '15:00MIAMI', 'UNIVERSITY', '-', 'OXFORD,', 'OHIO', 'Page:', '16Program:', 'SZRGRDT.SQRGrade', 'Distribution', 'by', 'Campus', 'and', 'by', 'DepartmentSections', 'of', '10Office', 'of', 'the', 'RegistrarSpring', 'Semester,', '2014-15Oxford', 'CampusGrade', 'key:', 'I', '=', 'Incomplete,', 'X', '=', 'Credit/No', 'Credit,', 'Y', '=', 'Research/Credit/No,', 'P', '=', 'Pass/Fail,', 'S', '=', 'Satisfactory', 'Progress']
```

Above is the text output, which corresponds to the pdf screenshot.

Comment: If you use a dataframe in pandas this should be quite easy.  Can you post the parsed example as text rather than image so I can test?

Comment: @Plato77 I've attached the parsed example as text in list form.

Comment: Can you tell me specifically which elements you want to extract from the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select specific elements in your data as a list, then try:

```
data = ['your list here']
data[3]
```

Will return value 113 as the output, for example.  It will probably be cleaner to use a pandas dataframe, it kind of depends if the data is in the same position each time.  Selecting specific grade types can be done, except when they go into double digits, then it will be tricky.